# Changing content in multiple classes via JS

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the HTML-value of the highlighted span below (`class=percent-value`):

```
<div id="verfuegbarstd" class="et_pb_number_counter_4" data-number-value="0" data-number-separator="">
  <div class="percent">
    <p>**<span class="percent-value">0</span>**<span class="percent-sign"></span></p>
  </div>
  <h3 class="title">Verfügbare Stunden</h3>
  <canvas height="0" width="0"></canvas>
</div>
```

I tried the following:

```
var verfuegbareStd = document.getElementsByClassName('et_pb_number_counter_4').getElementsByClassName('percent').getElementsByClassName('percent-value');
var budget = document.getElementsByClassName('et_pb_number_counter_2').getElementsByClassName('percent').getElementsByClassName('percent-value');
var lohnProStd = document.getElementsByClassName('et_pb_number_counter_3').getElementsByClassName('percent').getElementsByClassName('percent-value');
var gebrauchteStd = document.getElementsByClassName('et_pb_number_counter_5').getElementsByClassName('percent').getElementsByClassName('percent-value');
function calcVerfuegbareStd() {
  var calc = budget.innerHTML / lohnProStd.innerHTML;
  verfuegbareStd.innerHTML = calc;
}
calcVerfuegbareStd();
```

Does that make any sense?

Comment: Producing a `TypeError` normally doesn't make much sense -> [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByClassName returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name, as a NodeList object. So thats why i check the length. 
You can use also document.querySelector which gets the first element in the document with the class "xxxx" is returned.
I put both!
You can do it with jquery also but i thought you want pure js.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('percent-value'); // List of elements
var spanQuery = document.querySelector('.percent-value'); // The  first element in the document with the class "myclass" is returned:
spanQuery.innerHTML = 'Hello!!!';
if (elements.length > 0) {
  var span = elements[0];
  span.innerHTML = 'Hello!!!';
}
```

```html
<div id="verfuegbarstd" class="et_pb_number_counter_4" data-number-value="0" data-number-separator="">


  <div class="percent">
    <p>**<span class="percent-value">0</span>**<span class="percent-sign"></span></p>
  </div>
  <h3 class="title">Verfügbare Stunden</h3>
  <canvas height="0" width="0"></canvas></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("percent-value").innerHTML = "the content you want";
```

Comment: It is a collection. It will need var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('percent-value');
element[0] for the span

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to use `querySelector()`. This will return the first element.

```js
var verfuegbareStd = document.querySelector('.et_pb_number_counter_4 .percent .percent-value');

console.log(verfuegbareStd.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="verfuegbarstd" class="et_pb_number_counter_4" data-number-value="0" data-number-separator="">
  <div class="percent">
    <p>**<span class="percent-value">0</span>**<span class="percent-sign"></span></p>
  </div>
  <h3 class="title">Verfügbare Stunden</h3>
  <canvas height="0" width="0"></canvas>
</div>
```